# Problema al generar un drop down con PHPExcell

Tags: php, yii2

Hola buenas tardes estoy teniendo un problema idéntico cuando asigno a la celda la formula al generar el reporte no toma forma de drop down lo deja igual pero estoy generandolo con un rango de celdas.

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( new \PHPExcel_NamedRange( 'hiden_'.$cont_cat2, $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName(key($info)), 'A1:A'.count($hoja) ) );

$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($abc[$col].'2')
                            ->getDataValidation();
                        $objValidation->setType( \PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                        $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
                        $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                        $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
                        $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                        $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                        $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                        $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                        $objValidation->setFormula1('=hiden_1');
```

Comment: La pregunta en si no se entiende bien, se más específico y si es fuese necesario pon más código que de un contexto mejor de lo que ocupa

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad. También puedes revisar [como crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).